# Parse time periods

Tags: c

I have time format, that looks like this:

```
10:30-12:30,18:00-00:30 Mo-We,Th,Sa
```

and

```
Mo-Fr 08:00-13:30; Sa 08:00-12:30
```

Is there any easy and fast way to parse this? I need a function to compare current time to date in this formats.

**Is this standart format ?**

Comment: twoface88, where's the code you have tried for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a standard format. I'll try to split your problem in a few key parts:

1) **Data storage:**

Since the problem is limited to the days of the week, you could create an array of pairs of [tm structs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/) for each day of the week:

```
#include <time.h>

typedef tm interval[2];
typedef interval* daysofweek[7];

void main(void)
{
    int number_of_intervals = 2; //this must be calculated for each day but to exemplify how you could store your data I initialised it to 2
    interval *intervals;
    intervals = (interval*)malloc(number_of_intervals);
    daysofweek d;
    d[0] = intervals; //you must set the intervals for each day
}
```

2) **Parsing**

You should define a set of rules based on the sintax of the strings. From the two strings you exemplified I would define the following rules:

- split and treat separately all strings based on the `;` character
- split the resulted strings into a part with numerals (plus `-`, `:` and `,`) respectively a part with characters
- parse the part with numerals and create the time intervals
- parse the part with characters and populate the array for each day, keep track of all the days so that you can initialize the remaining days with 0 second intervals

3) **Comparison**

After you populated your data structure, you can parse it and deduce if you are in an interval or not by using the comparison functions found in [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/).

HTH,
JP.

P.S. if you would use C++ and STL instead of plain C, the task would be a bit easier.